# PostgreSQL: Common table expressions and Lateral Join

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

I would like to implement this:

```
with Period as
(
SELECT 
    dp.dtIni as dtRefPeriod,
    dp.dtEnd - p.days * interval '1 day' as dtIniWindow,
    dp.dtEnd,
    p.days
FROM public.vwDimPeriod dp
LEFT JOIN LATERAL ( select cast(vlParam as decimal(18,4)) as days
                    from public.DBParam
                    where cdparam = 'LifeTimeValueDays' ) p on TRUE
WHERE dp.dtEnd < CURRENT_DATE
)
,Orders as
(       
select 
    p.dtRefPeriod,
    o.nmEmail,
    dtOrder,
    p.dtIniWindow,
    p.dtEnd,
    o.cdOrder,
    o.vlOrder,
    p.days
from 
    public.vwFactOrder o
LEFT JOIN LATERAL Period p on TRUE
where
    ltrim(rtrim(o.nmEmail)) <> ''
    and o.blValid = B'1'
)
select * from Orders;
```

And I am getting an error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "p" LINE 1: ...rom public.vwFactOrder
>   o LEFT JOIN LATERAL Period p on TRUE ...
>                                                                ^ (execution time: 219 ms; total time: 437 ms)

Answer (score 0):

In your query you do not use the `LATERAL JOIN`: use columns of a previously specified relation for selecting columns/rows of another relation - so why use it at all? Furthermore, use of the CTE's is not necessary or useful in this query, so - unless there are things to your query that you do not show us - why not a simple query like so:

```
SELECT
    dp.dtIni AS dtRefPeriod,
    o.nmEmail,
    o.dtOrder,
    dp.dtEnd - p.days * interval '1 day' AS dtIniWindow,
    dp.dtEnd,
    o.cdOrder,
    o.vlOrder,
    p.days
FROM
    public.vwFactOrder o
    LEFT JOIN public.vwDimPeriod dp
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT cast(vlParam AS decimal(18,4)) AS days
                FROM public.DBParam
                WHERE cdparam = 'LifeTimeValueDays' ) p ON true
WHERE
    dp.dtEnd < CURRENT_DATE
    AND btrim(o.nmEmail) <> ''
    AND o.blValid;
```

Note that you are effectively making cross join because you do not specify any join conditions. In the case of `DBParam` that appears to be reasonable because they look like parameter values. If so and the parameters are always there and having a value, you do not need the `LEFT JOIN` but a simpler and more efficient `CROSS JOIN`. But you definitely want to review the join condition between the other two relations.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly that.